# Trying to take input from HTML form and storing it in MySQl Database

Tags: javascript, python, html, mysql, flask

In my flask app I am trying to take input from and HTML form in my modal to take input and store it in my database. the javascript and flask parts seem to be okay.

I am quite new to the flask framework, any and all suggestions are welcome :)

HTML

```html
<div class="modal-body">
              <form id="certificateForm">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="dateOfBaptism">Date of Baptism</label>
                      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dateOfBaptism" name="dateOfBaptism" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="registerNumber">Register Number</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registerNumber" name="registerNumber" required>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
```

js

```js
// Handle Save Changes button click in the modal
    $('#saveChangesButton').on('click', function() {
        var selectedRows = table.rows({ selected: true }).data().pluck(0); // Get selected row data
        var dateOfBaptism = $('#dateOfBaptism').val();
        var registerNumber = $('#registerNumber').val();

        // Perform validation if needed
        if (!dateOfBaptism || !registerNumber) {
            alert('Please fill in all fields.');
            return;
        }

        // Send an AJAX POST request to store the certificate data
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/store_certificate_data',
            data: {
                selectedRows: selectedRows.toArray(), // Convert to regular array
                dateOfBaptism: dateOfBaptism,
                registerNumber: registerNumber
            },
            success: function(response) {
                // Handle success response, e.g., redirect to preview page
                if (response.exists) {
                    // Data already exists, redirect to preview page with dataId
                    window.location.href = '/preview/' + response.dataId;
                } else {
                    // Data stored successfully, show a success message or perform further actions
                    alert('Certificate data stored successfully.');
                    $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('hide'); // Close the modal
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                // Handle errors
                alert('Error storing certificate data.');
            }
        });
    });
```

flask/python part:

```python
@app.route('/store_certificate_data', methods=['POST'])
def store_certificate_data():
    try:
        selected_rows = request.form.getlist('selectedRows[]')
        date_of_baptism = request.form['dateOfBaptism']
        register_number = request.form['registerNumber']

        cursor = db.cursor()

        # Check if the data already exists in the database
        query = "SELECT * FROM certificates WHERE selected_row IN (%s)"
        placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(selected_rows))
        cursor.execute(query % placeholders, tuple(selected_rows))
        existing_data = cursor.fetchall()

        if existing_data:
            # Data already exists, return response indicating existence and data id
            return jsonify({'exists': True, 'dataId': existing_data[0]['id']})
        else:
            # Data doesn't exist, insert new data and return success response
            insert_query = "INSERT INTO certificates (selected_row, date_of_baptism, register_number) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
            for row in selected_rows:
                try:
                    cursor.execute(insert_query, (row, date_of_baptism, register_number))
                    print(f"Inserted row {row} with date_of_baptism {date_of_baptism} and register_number {register_number}")
                except Exception as insert_error:
                    print(f"Error inserting row {row}: {str(insert_error)}")
            db.commit()
            return jsonify({'exists': False})

    except Exception as e:
        # Handle exceptions and errors appropriately
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)})
```

I tried all that i can from modifying my Js and forms. it POSTS but its not storing it in my database. FYI, my database is connected and it is working for other queris

Comment: There's quite a number of possibilities. If you know it's POSTing to server (verify via web developer tools) then I would make a simple curl statement posting to your endpoint which returns a hardcoded string to ensure it is even hitting your python code.